# Swagger with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, swagger

Page /v2/api-docs works just fine, the content is there, but when I try to open page /swagger-ui.html, I see the blank page like that:
[image]
I put the swagger ui dependency in pom.xml.

Did someone has this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Versions of these two dependencies MUST be the same.